# how to disable gcr-prompter dialogs?

Tags: emacs, password, gpg

Whenever i save *.gpg files (symmetric password) using emacs the gcr-prompter displays dialog and asks me for password twice! It's so annoying, especially that my emacs remembers the password i type, and when i press escape twice on the dialog boxes, emacs saves the file properly. How can i disable the annoying dialogs? Maybe uninstall gcr-prompter completely?

I use Linux Mint 17 x64 with Cinamon desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to .emacs:

```
;; Do not use gpg agent when runing in terminal
(defadvice epg--start (around advice-epg-disable-agent activate)
  (let ((agent (getenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO")))
    (setenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO" nil)
    ad-do-it
    (setenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO" agent)))
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16829842/3024945